# копировать строку с другого листа excel

Tags: excel

имею excel файл, на первой страницы имею столбце с текстом и необходимо найти этот текст ячейки на второй странице, если совпадение найдено, то необходимо скопировать всю строку и добавить в конце той строки где текст был найдет[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Лист где 6 строк ячейки С необходимо найти в листе где 21 строка, ячейки А

Извините, Я наверное не совсем понятно объясняю

[image: форматы таблиц такие]

Я нашел нечто подобное
=ПОИСКПОЗ(C3;результаты!A:A;0)
но результат это только номер необходимой мне строки

Answer (score 0):

```
=ВПР(C1;Лист2!$A$1:$M$100;СТОЛБЕЦ(A2);0)
```

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, но мне удалось решить проблему с помощью команды ИНДЕКС в связке с ПОИСКПОЗ

Comment: В данном случае практически одно и то же